# How to get Current scrollback position in tmux copy mode

Tags: tmux

Is there any existing way to get the current position in the scrollback buffer when I have scrolled back up in copy mode?

e.g.: I entered copy mode, scrolled back up quite a way up. and now the copy mode indicated shows `[36828/42969]`. I want to run something like

```
:display-message #{scrollback-position}#
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Further to the general case answered here, I came across this with the specific use case of exiting copy mode if the scroll position was zero.  It turns out there that `copy-mode -e` already provides this. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516142/tmux-key-binding-dependant-on-position-in-copy-mode/516152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the `tmux` source would require modification in order to access one of the two numbers as a format variable name. The larger number (42969 in this example) appears to be accessible as `history_size`, and it is visible in `format.c` via `tmux.h` as the `hsize` element of the `grid` element of `struct screen`, as seen in the first call to `format_add` in `format_defaults_pane`.

The smaller number (36828 in this example) appears to be the `oy` element of `struct window_copy_mode_data`, which is accessed in the `modedata` element of `struct window_pane` as a `void *`. In short, the smaller number is an element of a struct which is not visible within `format.c`. The `oy` element is used in `window_copy_write_line` to construct a string like the one mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was planning to dig into the code when i got some free time.

Comment: @woodstok Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @MarkPerryman, I have posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

From tmux 2.2 onwards, they have added a `scroll_position` variable. The [Tmux Manual](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#scroll_position) describes it as

`scroll_position - Scroll position in copy mode`.